# Displaying Bit Value as CheckBox in Telerik Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

I have a Telerik grid that is displayed a list of users. In my database, I have a bit field that determines if a user is priority or not. I am having an issue displaying it as a checkmark in Telerik window. It always come up as a drop down. I was able to get it to display as textbox; however, this option does not allow the user to manually group according to priority. The second way that I tried is failed and saying that 'CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type' see sample code below.

```
//the below example works fine, but it won't allow the user to sort. The automatic sort option is not available since it is an template.
 @* columns.Template(
              @<text> 
                    <input type="checkbox" name="prioprity" id="chkPriority" @(item.Users.PriorityUser == true ? "checked" : "unchecked") disabled="disabled"/> 
                </text>)
            .Width(60)
            .Title("Priority User");*@

 //The below example should  allow sorting. However, it throwing an exception 'CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type'

columns.Bound(x => x.Users.PriorityUser).Width(50)
            .ClientTemplate(
             @<text>
                <input type='checkbox' name='prioprity' id='chkPriority' @(item.User.PriorityUser == true ? "checked" : "unchecked")  disabled='disabled'/>
             </text>
            ).Title("Priority User")

//This attempt displays the data, but it is showing as a dropdown. 

columns.Bound(x => x.Users.PriorityUser).Width(50)
                .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' name='prioprity' id='chkPriority'@(item.Users.PriorityUser == true ? 'checked' : 'unchecked')  disabled='disabled'/>"
                ).Title("Priority User");
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved.
`columns.Bound(x => x.Users.PriorityUser).Width(50)` works just fine after I deleted the .edmx file and recreated it. Previously, I was simply doing an update from database to update the .edmx file.